# Shell Scripting: Store loop output in separate array

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I got the following script in which I am receiving sensor data from a host in a network. The data which I am receiving shall be stored in a separate array, called `output`, so that I can keep on working with the array output after the loop is finished. Currently the loop if overwriting the data which is stored in output, every time a new sensor data is received.

```
declare -a sensorData=(
    "1.3.6" #Data1
    "1.3.6" #Data2
)

declare -a output=()

for i in "${sensor[@]}"
do
    output=$(snmpget -v "snmpversion" -c  "ipaddress" "$i")
    echo $output
done
```

So the values I get from the `snmpget` command shall be stored in the array `output`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is right, but you just need to enclose the command substitution `$(..)` output to the array you defined. The `+=` operator allows you to append the `snmpget` output to the array in each iteration.

```
output+=( $(snmpget -v "snmpversion" -c  "ipaddress" "$i") )
```

Then you can loop over the array to get the values stored.

```
for val in "${output[@]}"; do
    printf "%s\n" "$val"
done
```

If you are worried about `IFS` and how the shell splits the each of the command output lines into the array, you can leave it to `mapfile` command, available in recent versions of `bash` (v4.0 or more I guess)

```
mapfile -t output < <(snmpget -v "snmpversion" -c  "ipaddress" "$i")
```

and then run the loop over the output array as before. However this does not apply when you want to *append* to the array, but just run the command once.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. It works very well, but as you said, the shell is splitting the command output, which isnt much of a problem atm. Also thank for your mapfile mention, good and fast answer :)